# Have Visual Studio suggest preferred opposite of !Variable or !Property

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to define or have Visual Studio suggest a preferred opposite of a variable/property when it sees `!variable` or `!Property` in code?

Example:

`isDraft` is the opposite of `isFinalized`

It's fine to use `!isFinalized` to mean `isDraft` or `!isDraft` to mean `isFinalized`, but is there a way to prefer the opposite variable instead of then negated variable?

Answer (score 2):

You're going into "analyzer" territory. Meaning you need to code a semantic difference between your human concepts of "opposite" into a syntactic difference that a compiler can understand.

You can certainly do this. It means pairing properties and their fields with their opposites by parsing "name of property". I see this happening by

1. Declaring an attribute on a field with an attribute on the "opposite" field. Or by inspecting the static definition of one in terms of the other.
2. Link them through those attributes or walking the static tree.
3. Write an analyzer that understands this linkage that can be run at a pre-compile step.
4. Write an optional fix, that allows you to suggest what the user can do.

This is beyond the scope of normal compilation because it involves some semantics that need to be encoded at the analyzer stage. Clearly "opposite" would have to be something that you encode in your framework that the analyzer can use.

> This is non-trivial.

That said, it's possible, but *will* involve your "business rules" during the static analysis phase keyed off of words and their perceived opposites.

> **This is *not* built in.**

The clearest example of something similar are projects like [Humanizr](https://humanizr.net/), but this is done at runtime. They do this for plural/singular for example.

Comment: Thanks! At least now I know it's not simple config or checkbox setting change somewhere.

Comment: If you have special requirements for this, you can go to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home) of VS to send your request. If this answer helped you, you can mark it as an answer, which can help others with the same problem.